# Get username to check if file exists in Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

The web page that I am building has a download button. I am writing a test to check that the file is successfully downloaded and check that the file exists. So, I am using

```
cy.readFile('/home/username/Downloads/file.txt').should('exist');
```

This is working as the path is specified. To ensure that this test works successfully in all local machines I want to derive the 'username' instead of hard-coding it. I am using the following approach:

```
import os from 'os';
const username = os.userInfo().username;
cy.readFile(`/home/${username}/Downloads/file.txt`).should('exist');
```

Although the username is getting correctly populated when I am running this segment as a separate javascript file, however, it is failing in Cypress - giving a 'WebPack Module' error.
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you download the file for test purpose only, why not into /tmp directory? You wouldn't have to bother with username then.